# ZSH directory expansion ('..' into '../')

Tags: zsh, expansion, tabexpansion

I've recently started to learn and use ZSH.

The problem I'm facing is that ZSH won't auto-expand '..' in commands (like 'cd', 'cp' and so on) into '../'. Bash does this.

This wouldn't be such an big issue if I were using keyboard with US-layout... but in scandinavia '/' is behind SHIFT+7 so hitting  is much faster.

How would I go on and implement such automatic expansion? I'm usin 'Oh my ZSH' package. Typing CTRL+xh after typing 'cd ..' gives the following:

```
21:16:50 amjr@imac development ruby-1.9.2-p290 cd ..
tags in context :completion::complete:cd::
    local-directories named-directories      (_alternative _cd (eval)) 
    users named-directories directory-stack  (_tilde _alternative _cd (eval)) 
    users                                    (_users _tilde _alternative _cd (eval))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want zsh to add a `/` when you've just typed `..`? Or when you press `TAB` after `..`? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

What I was trying to achieve is that when I hit  after typing '..' it would expand it into '../'.

I managed to get this working by adding:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true
```

into my .zshrc